# MySQL Query: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting following error message.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\my\include\user_functions.php on line 34
```

Here is my Code

```
$conn = db_connection();
    if($conn == false) {
        user_error('Unable to connect to database');
        return false;
    }
    $query = "UPDATE user SET passwd = '".$new_passwd."'
            WHERE username = '".$username."'  ";

    $result=$conn->query($query);
    if($result == false) {
        user_error('Query Error'.$conn->error);
        return false;
    }           

    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo 'Password changed';
    } else {
            echo 'Failed ';
    }
```

here is my db_connection

```
function db_connection() {
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','php_login');
    if(!$db) {
        echo 'Could not connect to database server';
    } else {
        return $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure why are you trying to return `$result->fetch_array;` `$result` what if `$result->num_rows == 0` besides ... check answer

Comment: well can you show me in which line did you get the error. i.e. `\user_functions.php on line 34` means which line

Comment: this is line no 34 =  `if($result->num_rows == 1)`

Comment: well what does `$conn->query($query)` return? is `num_rows` attribute of `$result` or `$conn`. I suppose it should be `$conn` property rather that `$result` also make sure that it is present there.

Comment: and please use @displayname [@experimentX in my case] while replying so that I can be alerted if not in my post and if you add your `db` class it might be more helpful

Comment: @experimentX My password changed in database. But still getting that error. I print this line `echo $result` it return 1

Comment: change `$result->num_rows == 1`  to  `$conn->num_rows == 1` also please show your `db` class it would be more useful. I think the error is there because `result` just contains Boolean value not an object `$conn` is your object and it should hold properties

Comment: @experimentX - I changed `$result->num_rows == 1` to `$conn->num_rows == 1`. Now I'm getting this error. `Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\my\include\user_functions.php on line 35
not changed`. But my password changing in the database. which `db class`?

Comment: `new mysqli('localhost','root','','php_login');` class. and of course if you password is changing then your code is working so if you remove `if($result->num_rows == 1) { .. ` you should get fine and working. In your class `mysqli` class i suppose you don't have `$num_rows` property

Comment: why did you get your problem solved, i will update my answer anyway check

Comment: @user559744, I sure hope your are hashing `$new_password` with salt before updating that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
class mysqli{

    public $aff_num_rows;
    //some properties
    //some properties

    //some methods
    //some methods

    public function query($sql)
    {
        $resultset = mysql_query($sql); //after query instantiate the $aff_numrows
                        //property with function 
        $this->aff_num_rows = mysql_affected_rows(); //guess you are using sqlite
        //so you might have different function
        //and you can use this property 
    }   

}
```

And in you code you have

```
if($conn->aff_num_rows == 1) {
    echo 'password changed';
} else {
        echo 'error changing pasword';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UPDATE` statement doesn't return a result set.  What are you trying to get from `fetch_array`?